# Understanding Fermion-Antifermion Transitions through Higgs Field Interaction

Tags: higgs

I understand that the vacuum expectation value (vev) of the Higgs field has changed, resulting in a nonzero energy value throughout space. It takes the shape of a Mexican hat, with its minima less than zero. Therefore, there exists a Yukawa that interacts with fermions.

$$\mathcal{L}_\text{Yukawa} = -g \bar{\psi}\phi\psi $$

In Yukawa interaction, $$ \bar{\psi}\phi\psi $$ represents the interaction between two fermions (described by \psi) through the exchange of a Higgs boson (described by \phi).

Examples:

Electron: \psi_e is the electron field (charge -1), while \bar{\psi}_e is the antielectron field (charge +1) (not the same as positron).

Up quark: \psi_u is the up quark field (charge +2/3), while \bar{\psi}_u is the up antiquark field (charge -2/3).

**This means that thanks to the interaction with the Higgs field, particles undergo transitions between fermions and antifermions ? It's right?**

If the above is correct, then there should be a frequency at which fermions transition between fermions and antifermions. How is that frequency calculated?